# facebook comment plugin

Tags: facebook-comments

I'm using the facebook comment plugin on my website. I've also created a facebook page for my company. When users comment using the facebook plugin on the website, how do I get these posts to post directly to my facebook page for the company instead of my profile page?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do so without writing your own comments plugin.